# Default class fields values during JAXB unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

What happened if there is no value for some class fields in xml file during JAXB unmarshalling? JAXB just "omit" this value and left them uninitialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they will get initialized.

Initial values for fields will be set and the no-arg constructor will also run.

for example:

```
class AClass {

    private int x = 5;
    private int y = 16;
    private Object object;

    public AClass() {
        this.x = 100;
    }

    // getters and setters
    // ...

}
```

if the values in the xml for x, y, z and object are omitted there valus will be:

x: 100 (the constructor runs after the field value initialization)
y: 16 (from the field value initialization)
object: null (objects get initialized to null if no value is given)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the fields will be initialized with the default values​​, depending on the type of field?

Comment: initialization goes in following order: first the default values according to type, then the values you gave them on declaration and then the constructor runs wich might set a value.

Comment: Thats great! :D